# Driver not specified for this database connection: default

Tags: drush, drupal-9

I have moved a drupal 9.5.9 from a staging server to another staging server. The site is working absolutely fine in the first staging server. But when I migrated the full website to the second server & run `./vendor/bin/drush cr` to clear caches, it's showing that driver not specified.

I even tried to remove namespace & driver from database array but it couldn't work.

The database connection:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'db_name',
  'username' => 'db_user',
  'password' => 'db_pass'
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

The error we got:

[drush cr error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzyLR.png)